# datepicker button disable when change from search by month to today's date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am having issues with datepicker when I picked search by month and pick a random month the button will be able to click but when I changed it to today's date the button will be disabled. But if you choose another day and choose back to today's date the button will be able again.

Here is my code base for my datepicker:

```
        <DatePicker
          customInput={
            <React.Fragment>
              <input
                tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
                className="exact-date-input"
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                autoComplete="off"
                type="text"
                maxLength={10}
                id="date-input"
                aria-label={ariaLabel}
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownDateType}
                onClick={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(true, this.state.error)}
                onFocus={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(true, this.state.error)}
                onBlur={()=>this.emptyIfError(this.state.error)}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          openToDate={this.openToDate(this.props.value)}
          tabIndex={-1}
          selected={this.openToDate(this.props.value)}
          customInputRef="dateInput"
          autoComplete="off"
          id={this.props.id}
          onChange={this.handleInput}
          required={this.props.required}
          minDate={moment(today).toDate()}
          maxDate={moment(endRange).toDate()}
          open={this.state.datePickerIsOpen}
          onClickOutside={()=>this.openOrCloseDatePicker(false, this.state.error)}
        />
```

and here is my button:

```
            <button className={(validForm || !hasAnyContractSelected) ? "form-action-button mv-button primary disabled" : "form-action-button mv-button primary"} tabIndex={7} disabled={validForm || !hasAnyContractSelected} type="button" onClick={() => {this.onSubmit()}}>
              <span className="search-carat">{localize('static.content.search')}</span>
            </button>
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error? and how can I fix it?

Here is the photo that search button is able to click:
[image]

and here is unable:
[image]

Updated toggle button:

```
  <div className="mv-toggle-inner" style={{ position: "relative" }} tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex} onKeyDown={this.toggleOnSpace}>
    <Toggle
      icons={false}
      name={this.props.name}
      id={this.props.name}
      checked={this.props.checked}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      tabIndex={-1}
    />
```

added onChange function:

```
  toggleOnSpace(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      let newEvent = {
        target: {
          name: this.props.name,
          type: "checkbox",
          checked: !this.props.checked,
        },
      };
      this.props.onChange(newEvent);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Updated and add validForm:

```
let validForm = !(
  this.validate(this.formRequirements, this.props.form).length === 0
) || !this.props.criteria.enableOwnerSearchAvailability;
```

Comment: Anyone have idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have to post as answer because I don't have enough points to make comment.

I want to know about this on your button:

`disabled={validForm || !hasAnyContractSelected}`

I think validForm is set once you switch from month to actual date because choosing month is not valid, then choosing date makes it valid

Comment: You mean the problem is from switch button ?

Comment: i think when it is switch, it causes validForm = true .. and this makes Search Button disabled - `disabled={validForm || !hasAnyContractSelected}`.  It's just an idea

Comment: Yea, let me add switch button code in my post!

Comment: 2 things, what if you change to !validForm? -> `disabled={!validForm || !hasAnyContractSelected}` and also, would like to see this fucntion: `onChange={this.props.onChange}`

Comment: just updated and added onChange function!

Comment: I just updated and add validForm